# How to get selenium to work on WSL2 for windows?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, windows-subsystem-for-linux

Im trying to get selenium to work on WSL2 with Ubuntu but it doesnot seem to work. Whats a bigger issue however is that I cannot pinpoint the exact cause of this because my google searches turn up nothing on the matter. The error I seem to be getting is:

Code:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

driver.get("http://selenium.dev")

driver.quit()
```

Error:

```
SessionNotCreatedException: Message: session not created exception: Missing or invalid capabilities
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.37.544315 (730aa6a5fdba159ac9f4c1e8cbc59bf1b5ce12b7),platform=Linux 5.10.102.1-microsoft-standard-WSL2 x86_64)
```

So from my understanding - its detecting the driver but then not running it? Is there a way to fix this ?